# Preventing user from accessing/requesting more then one application pool connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

My company recently had an issue where a user did a get request on our main page 6 times a second for 30 minutes. Each time they performed this get request we hit the aspstate database to set a session identifier.

The problem here is that every time this happened they received 6 new app pool connections, and assigning the connections seems to happen faster than releasing them (assigning them happens instantly, releasing can take up to half a second).

The result is that we run out of connections in the app pool, and a long stream of "Connection Timeout" errors happen as new users (or even those 6/sec from this one user) are scramble to get connections that no longer exist.

Question 1: Has anyone seen this before? Besides it being a dedicated attack on us (unlikely), I can't really figure out why one user would do that many requests on our page.

Question 2: Is there a way to prevent a user from retrieving more than one or two app pool connections?

Comment: Do you have the app pool set up to have >1 worker process? Something about web garden needing you to keep the connection alive to prevent it from spawning new ones: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720391%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: The maximum worker process is at 1.